# VB.NET Reportviewer How to make Inner Join work properly

Tags: sql, vb.net, reportviewer

I have 2 tables

tableAssembly, with columns SerialNumber, Brick1SerialNumber, Brick2SerialNumber,DateInserted

tableBricks, with columns SerialNumber, Lot, Weight, DateMeasured

In VB.NET(WinForms) I have been able to get the reportviewer control to work and print out information from both tables and also to enable/disable columns, and apply filters such as LIKE

In case it isn't clear tableAssembly.Brick1SerialNumber = tableBricks.SerialNumber

What I now want to do is when a user prints out a report from tableAssembly, I want them to be able to filter based on Brick1SerialNumber.Lot or Brick2SerialNumber.Lot or Brick1SerialNumber.DateMeasured or Brick2SerialNumber.DateMeasured

I understand I need to INNER JOIN tableAssembly.Brick1SerialNumber = tableBricks.SerialNumber AND tableAssembly.Brick2SerialNumber = tableBricks.SerialNumber

Do I also need to INNER JOIN the other columns from tableBricks to columns in tableAssembly? or does the INNER JOIN of Brick1SerialNumber = SerialNumber and Brick2SerialNumber = Serial make it so I can filter based on .Lot?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this.  1) join to tableBricks twice (probably not necessary for this condition) or attach it once, using both foreign keys (works for this condition, but not for all conditions).

Try this query:

```
SELECT tableAssembly.*
FROM tableAssembly INNER JOIN tableBricks 
   ON tableAssembly.Brick1SerialNumber = tableBricks.SerialNumber 
   OR tableAssembly.Brick2SerialNumber = tableBricks.SerialNumber
WHERE tableBricks.Lot = 99 --actually means Brick1.Lot or Brick2.Lot
  AND tableBricks.DateMeasured = '1/1/2000'
```

If you need a specific Lot or DateMeasured for Brick1 and Brick2 (not the same values), then try this query:

```
SELECT tableAssembly.*
FROM tableAssembly INNER JOIN tableBricks AS tableBricks1
   ON tableAssembly.Brick1SerialNumber = tableBricks1.SerialNumber 
INNER JOIN tableBricks AS tableBricks2
   ON tableAssembly.Brick2SerialNumber = tableBricks2.SerialNumber
WHERE tableBricks1.Lot = 98
  AND tableBricks2.Lot = 99
  AND tableBricks1.DateMeasured = '1/1/2000'
  AND tableBricks2.DateMeasured = '1/2/2000'
```